# Why is UnicodeText being changed to TEXT in SQLALchemy & giving Operational error when used with MariaDB?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, mariadb

I'm trying to run a webserver in a docker container, connecting to a local mysql (mariadb) database. I can connect to the database fine but when altering the database I get the following errors which I don't understand. If the table fields are declared as UnicodeText, why are they being changed to Text or Varchar later? Do I need to add something to the declarations (length)?

In user.models.py, the following table declaration:

```
__tablename__ = "users"
    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = Column(UnicodeText, unique=True, nullable=False)
    salt = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    password = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.datetime.utcnow)
    first_name = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    last_name = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    active = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
    is_admin = Column(Boolean(), default=False)
    api_token = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
```

Error produced at run time:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
> (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column
> 'username' used in key specification without a key length") [SQL:
> CREATE TABLE users (  user_id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
> username TEXT NOT NULL,     email TEXT NOT NULL,    salt TEXT,
> password TEXT,      created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,   first_name TEXT,
> last_name TEXT,     active BOOL,    is_admin BOOL,      api_token TEXT,
> PRIMARY KEY (user_id),      UNIQUE (username),      UNIQUE (email),     CHECK
> (active IN (0, 1)),   CHECK (is_admin IN (0, 1)) )

Also in same traceback:

> sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'plot_config', column 'data'):
> VARCHAR requires a length on dialect mysql

Presumably related to this table in models.py:

```
__tablename__ = "plot_config"
    config_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    config_type = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    config_name = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)
    config_dataset = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=True)
    data = Column(UnicodeText, nullable=False)

    fav_users = db.relationship(
        "User", secondary=user_plotconfig_map, backref="favourite_plotconfigs"
    )
```

Comment: Try using `Unicode` and specify a (maximum) length, e.g., `Unicode(50)`.

Answer (score 0):

UnicodeText translates to TEXT in mysql / mariadb. But TEXT is "unbounded" - does not have the length specified. Such columns cannot be used in indexes. Which is exactly what the error message says:

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'username' used in key specification without a key length
```

(unique implies a key).

Do you really need unbounded strings? You will be better off using Unicode and specifying a length. For example

```
username = Column(Unicode(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = Column(Unicode(100), unique=True, nullable=False)
```